# Group by isnull: what problems will I have, and is there a better alternative?

Tags: sql, group-by

here the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5945f/1

I have values both 0 and null, and I don't want to them to be distinct. I want them to be treated as identical. So (2, 0) and (2, null) should be grouped to (2, 0) or (2, null), doesn't matter. I found that solution I provided in the fiddle is working. But is it fine to do that? Also is there a way to not to write isnull() second time in select?

Comment: . . Your answer is fine.  I prefer to use `coalesce()` (in general) because it is the ANSI standard function for this functionality.

Comment: thanks, I've read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx and it seems that isnull is a better alternative, as it's evaluated only once.

Comment: . . It is better when the first argument is complex (such as a subquery).  In other situations, the difference in performance isn't important.  One hopes that Microsoft will actually fix this problem instead of documenting it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem with the way you do it.

Regarding your second question: Some DBMSs (like SQL Anywhere) allow to use aliases in the `group by`, but some (like Oracle and SQL Server) do not. If the DBMS allows to use aliasses in group by, you could write:

```
select id, isnull(price, 0) as pr
  from foo
group by id, pr;
```

Comment: yes, I thought that maybe there is something like that for sql server, but it seems, that I'll have to write second isnull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the second `ISNULL` at the cost of a subquery.

```
select id, pr
from
    (select id, isnull(price, 0) as pr from foo) t
group by id, pr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just pass the column, that you use in any even non-aggregate function, into group by clause.

```
select id, isnull(price, 0) [Product Price]
  from foo f
group by f.id, f.price;
```

Variants above didn't work for me.